Elasticsearch full document vs page by page text indexing
I am building a web app on .Net & PostgreSql.
One of the requirements is to upload a lot of documents like 200 of them which can be on a few formats like pdf, doc, rtf, odt.
I am currently storing them in Elasticsearch.
So when a document is uploaded I use the Toxy nuget package to extract the whole document text and index it in Elasticsearch.
The files can me max 50 mb and there could be a large number of documents with arount 100-200 pages.
Currently it works good but I need to return as a result also the place/page that the search match was found.
Any suggestions or insights what would be a good approach to do this?
Also what is the best practice, full text indexing or partial/page by page indexing of documents in ElasticSearch.

Like you said, instead of indexing the entire document as one entry, spliting the document into pages and indexing each page as a separate document with fields like document_id, page_number, and content is a good solution.
You can use Apache Tika to do the extraction.
You can use search query with highlighting for requests:
{
  "query": {
    "match": { "content": "search term" }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {}
    }
  }
}


You cant split the document by pages using Apache Tika since it will give you the full document text, I can only split the content by lets say number of words or some other measure.
